# How to pass out focus of input when clicked out?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I'm using next js for my application, and I am designing a search field. The suggestions start coming in once the user types something, but I would like to hide it when the input bar is not in focus.

When the user clicks on it again, I would like to show it back. The search suggestions contain routes, so I am not able use `onFocus` and `onBlur` as the element loses focus when I register a click and the route happens only when I release it.

I tried css too, but I'm not able to register the focus out, or is there a way?

Please help me out!!

Here is my sample code:

```
const [suggestionState,setSuggestionState] = useState(false);


<input type="input"
                    
  ref={inputRef}
  autoFocus
  className={styles['search-bar-input']}
  onFocus={()=>{setSuggestionState(true)}}
  onBlur={()=>{setSuggestionState(false)}}
  placeholder="Search Bloggo"
  onChange={(e)=>{

      var trimmedQuery = e.target.value;
      trimmedQuery = trimmedQuery.trim(); 
      setSearchQuery(trimmedQuery);
      getSuggestions(trimmedQuery)

  }}
  onKeyDown={(e)=>{handleKeypress(e)}}

/>
{

searchQuery.length == 0 || suggestionState == false? '':

<div className={styles['search-bar-suggestions']}>
  <Link>... </Link>
</div>
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you use two variables (suggestion_state_by_input_focus and suggestion_state_by_search_suggestion_focus) and show the list when either one of them is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with css [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

```css
.suggestions {
  display: none;
}

form:focus-within .suggestions {
  display: block;
}

input:focus~.suggestions {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="input" placeholder="Search Bloggo" value="">
  <div class="suggestions">Suggestions...
    <div><a href="#">Suggestion 1</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Suggestion 2</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Suggestion 3</a></div>
    <div><a href="#">Suggestion 4</a></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

---

Applying the above in react might looks something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState("");
  const [results, setResults] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!searchQuery) {
      setResults([]);
      return;
    }
    fetch(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?name=${searchQuery}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(({ results }) => setResults(results));
  }, [searchQuery]);

  return (
    <form>
      <input
        value={searchQuery}
        type="input"
        autoFocus
        placeholder="Search Bloggo"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setSearchQuery(e.target.value);
        }}
      />

      {!!results.length && (
        <div className={`suggestions `}>
          <h3>Suggestions</h3>
          {results.map((result) => {
            return (
              <Link key={result.id} url={result.url}>
                {result.name}
              </Link>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      )}
    </form>
  );
}

const Link = ({ url, children }) => (
  <div>
    <a href={url}>{children}</a>
  </div>
);
```

[image: Edit vigorous-joana-l93oy]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!, where can I learn more about the `~` in css?

Comment: It is called a `General sibling combinator` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator

Comment: Much appreciated! Thank you!